# Expected type 'Canvas', got 'int' instead

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title('Pomodoro timer')
window.config(padx=100, pady=50)
canvas = Canvas(width=200, height=224)
tomato_img = PhotoImage(file="C:/vscode/tomato.png")
canvas.create_image(102, 112, image=tomato_img)
Canvas.create_text(102, 112, text='00:00')
canvas.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

This is the code that I'm working on

when I'm trying to add two integers for x and y co-ordinates to the Canvas.create_text function, it gives me this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\pycharm and thonny\pythonProject1\main.py", line 26, in <module>
    Canvas.create_text(102, 112, text='00:00')
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2810, in create_text
    return self._create('text', args, kw)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '_create'
```

Comment: You have `canvas.create_image` (lowercase) and `Canvas.create_text` (uppercase), is that on purpose?

Comment: As @IgnatiusReilly said, it is typo: `Canvas.create_text(...)` should be `canvas.create_text(...)`.